# Why this code is not returning max value present in variable?

Tags: python, list, python-requests

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())

    a = max(arr)
    print(a)
```

sample input:

> 5

> 45566

output:

> 6

This code is not returning the maximum value present in variable.

Comment: Please, update more information about your issue. This helps you avoid being voted. I'm really do not understand what you say.

Comment: Pls provide sample input so helpers can reproduce your issue. Also fix your indentation, what you are showing is not valid Python.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your output given your code and sample input.

Comment: what result do you expect ? what result do you get?

Comment: maybe split code to simpler elements - ie . `a = input()`,  `b = a.split()`, etc.  and use `print()` to see values in variables - ie. `print(a)`, `print(b)` and you will see if code is working as you expect. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: if you expece result `6` then you need `list(input())` instead of `input().split()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want tread number `45566` as five numbers `4,5,5,6,6` then you need `list(arr)` instead of `arr.split()`

If you split code to simpler lines then you can use `print()` to see where is the problem.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = int(input())
    
    arr = input()
    #print('input:', arr)
    
    #arr = arr.split()
    #print('split:', arr)

    arr = list(arr)
    print('list:', arr)
    
    arr = map(int, arr)
    print('map(int):', arr)

    a = max(arr)
    print(a)
```